# Use JavaScript resourceBundle object in more convenient way

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have following resourceBundle object in javascript.

```
var resourceBundle = {
    en : {
        "EX_ONE" : "Example One",
                "EX_TWO" : "Example One",
                "EX_THREE" : "Example One"
        }
        fr : {
        "EX_ONE" : "ExampleD Uno",
                "EX_TWO" : "Exampled Twono",
                "EX_THREE" : "Exampled theree"
        }
}
```

But the thing is, it is very bad practice when ever to add a label, I have to come here, add new key value to all the languages.I mean here is only English and (wrong) French. But what if there are other languages. Can you suggest me a better way, like what we use properties file for jsp and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `.properties` resource bundle file under classpath (WEB-INF/classess) like this:

resources.properties

```
EX_ONE=Example One
EX_TWO=ExampleTwo
EX_THREE=Example Three
```

resources_fr.properties

```
EX_ONE=ExampleD Uno
EX_TWO=Exampled Twono
EX_THREE=Exampled theree
```

In your JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<%
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources");
// your language is based on current locale set in request/session
String exOne=resource.getString("EX_ONE");
String exTwo=resource.getString("EX_TWO");
%>
Your localized text here:
<%
System.out.println(exOne);
System.out.println(exTwo);
%>
```

Comment: yes buddy,I get that.But there is already html created in js files.I am doing a conversion, so its should be in js level.Dynamic text are created in js from the ajax response

Comment: localization for client side, I implemented by using a dynamic page that is going to load all keys and values for current language, built a map like your example, but there no "en" or "fr" in map - whatever current language from the server. Include the (javascript map) jsp above as a (dynamic) javascript file. Use those key like resourceBundle.EX_ONE, resourceBundle.EX_TWO